# Not able to connect to remote windows server winrm, from one machine. Other machine works and test-netconnection to 5985 also works

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, winrm

I have 3 computer 01, 010994 and 024166. Now, from 010994 I am able to successfully run `test-wsman 01` and it works but from 024166 it gives me following error

```
test-wsman : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsmanfault" Code="2150858770"             Machine="024166.company.com"><f:Message>The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.    Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation
for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM
service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".
</f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:1
+ test-wsman 01.test.tst
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (01.test.tst:String) [Test-WSMan], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.TestWSManCommand
```

I have verified

```
Test-NetConnection 01.test.tst -port 5985
ComputerName     : 01.hqtest.tst
RemoteAddress    : 
RemotePort       : 5985
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
SourceAddress    : 
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

My event log also show a event with id 254 Activity transfer before showing the same error in event log.